# Text editor to write comments onto comment layer of PDF, edit FDF or PSL File

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have an ebook reader, on which I can make annotations onto pdf, e.g. mark text. The reader (Hanvon E960) creates a .pdf.psl file and if this is next to the PDF, then when I open it on my desktop I can see my markings.

Likewise then I make comments in the Acrobat Reader, it creates a .fdf file, which captures the comments. 
My question is, is there a proper editor for this. The File is reasonably lean and is an xml version 1.0 file.

It would be so much better if you could edit this in a data structure type, export to Excel into a column type and start adding items.

Any ideas ?